# Laravel routes return 404 after moving to XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, laravel, mod-rewrite, xampp

I've read some posts about it and found, that the problem is with mod_rewrite. But my configs seems to be ok.

My vhosts.conf:

```
<Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/example/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted  
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/example/public"
    ServerName example.localhost
    ServerAlias www.example.localhost 
</VirtualHost>
```

My .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

My httpd.conf:

```
#LoadModule request_module modules/mod_request.so
#LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
#LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so
#LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so
```

And phpinfo() also tells me, that mod_rewrite is loaded.

My example route:

```
Route::get('/', function()
    {
        return 'Hello World';
    });
```

So, where i should look?

Comment: Does Laravel give you any error message (if no, please check error logs)? Did you set write permissions on a `storage` folder?

Comment: @Alexey No new messages in log (storage/logs/larave.log), permissions is ok.

Comment: Please check also Apache log

Comment: @Alexey also no new messages in apache log

Comment: It was mistake in code, nothing wrong with .htaccess or XAMPP, sory everyone.